# Python possible to run while loop until RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Tags: python, recursion, error-handling, runtime, runtime-error

I'm running a recursive loop to achieve the maximum optimization for something and am reaching a point where the code hits a `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python objec`t. This is expected, but I want to stop the code right at the point before it hits that error, so I can view my data at that point.

Is it possible to have a while loops saying something similar to that? Something like "Hey, run this loop until you reach maximum recursion depth. Once reached, stop and return."

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you can use pdb to catch it at the error and inspect the environment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the following

```
def recurse():
  try:
    recurse()
  except RuntimeError as e:
    if e.message == 'maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object':
      # don't recurse any longer
    else:
      # something else went wrong
```

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html

NOTE: it might be worth while to find out the error number of the max recursion depth error and check for that instead of the error string.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, have the recursive call in a try/except RuntimeError block? When the except is called return the value.

EDIT: Yes this is possible, like so:

```
def recursion(i):
    try:
        return recursion(i+1)
    except RuntimeError:
        return i

a=0
print recursion(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Store `sys.maxrecursionlimit()` as a variable (say `maxrec`) in a more global scope. Each time you recurse, deduct `1` from `maxrec`. Check before the recursion, though to make sure that `maxrec` is not `0`. If `maxrec` hits `0`, you'll know that you've hit the recursion limit and you can escape.

```
def myFunc(params):
    # do stuff
    if maxrec <= 0:
        return # return whatever you need to
    if maxrec > 0:
        maxrec -= 1
        myFunc(params)

maxrec = sys.getrecursionlimit()
myFunc(params)
```

Hope this helps